# How do i set the value of a json var as a input from html

Tags: javascript, html, json, discord

Iv'e tried quite abit of thing and it doesn't work, im trying to get it to send a discord webhook and i can't get it, the closest iv'e got was a post error, idk what it means or if its my json var
here is my code or what i have

```
function sendMessage() {
  var textimput = document.getElementById("userInput");

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(
    "POST",
    "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1234567890/1234567890qwertyuiosdfghxcvbn"
  );

  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  var i = 0;

  var message = {
    content: "Text",
    embeds: [
      {
        title: "Title",
        description: "message",
        color: 16711680,
        footer: {
          text: "Footer",
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  message.embeds[0].description = textimput;
  request.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

I have the input set like this

```
<input id="userInput" placeholder="INSERT TEXT LINK HERE">
```

Comment: Expand a bit on 'cant get it'. What was the error message for you  'POST error'?

Comment: i want it to post an embed from a webhook into my discord server, but it leaves the description blank

Comment: Try instead of `message.embeds[0].description = textimput` use `message.embeds[0].description = textimput.value`

Comment: thank you, ive been trying to do that for almost 5 hours now! thx alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
var textimput = document.getElementById("userInput")
```

with

```
var textimput = document.getElementById("userInput").value
```

You sent the input element instead of it's value